# Fetch products on store procedure asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures

i am trying to get products according to category id from store procedure. i really don't know how to. i tried some code which is as follows.

```
 public ActionResult category(int id)
    {
        cakemakeEntities DB = new cakemakeEntities();
        var pdata = DB.products_all.Where(model => model.cat_id == id);
        if (pdata != null)
        {
            TempData["cateID"] = id;
            TempData.Keep();
            return View(pdata);
        }
        return View();
    }
```

this is my store procedure name.

> products_all

int id on category bracket i am getting it from url parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are getting id value from Url Parameter.